# how to get the format of date in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

i have saved date format on database like 
2019-01-16
I want to check if current date is not greater that current date it return valid othersise invalid.
I have issue it return invalid.
how to get this format? 
I'm not getting valid result with this format.

```
   $date = new Date('Y-M-D');

  if ($date <= response.data[i]['card_expiry_date']){
       status = "<button class='btn btn-success'>Valid</button>";
  }else{
       status = "<button class='btn btn-danger'>Invalid</button>";
  }
```

Comment: Are you doing this on the server side?

Comment: i'm doing this on blade template.

Comment: what is this `Date()`. what is the fully qualified name of `Date()`

Comment: i dont know i just want to get current date. So i tried this.

Comment: Try printing both and appending the output to the question.

Comment: try $date = date('Y-m-d');

Comment: I'm assuming the code you've shown in your question is inside a `<script>` block?

Comment: @RossWilson yes

Comment: that means Date() is Javascript, not php ?

Comment: @AmritShrestha tried it gets error Uncaught ReferenceError: date is not defined

Comment: I seed $ and my mind didn't see other things, my bad. please console.log the $date and  response.data[i]['card_expiry_year'] and try to compare it manually first.

Comment: @TharakaDilshan i'm using php variable in script . i have also tried by doing 'var date'

Comment: in that case you need to enclose variables inside {{ }}

Comment: $date = new Date();
console.log($date.getFullYear() + '-' +($date.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + $date.getDate()  );

Comment: @AmritShrestha its working but where we can do this outside console.log()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185931/discussion-between-izza-and-amrit-shrestha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to pass the date from the response to `new Date` as well:

```
var now = new Date();
var expiry = new Date(response.data[i]['card_expiry_date']);

if (now.getTime() <= expiry.getTime()) {
    status = "<button class='btn btn-success'>Valid</button>";
} else {
    status = "<button class='btn btn-danger'>Invalid</button>";
}
```

Comment: i want this format '2019-01-16'.. i'm getting 'Sun Dec 30 2018 14:24:01'

Comment: @izza Are you displaying the date to the user as well or just using it to compare against the current date for your if statement?

Comment: as i told in question description if current date is is less the date stored in database it returns valid on view.

Comment: @izza Yeah, I read that part of you're question. My point is that it shouldn't matter what format the date is in since you're passing it to Date. I've have updated my answer as some browsers might not compare the Date objects themselves correctly.

Comment: still i'm getting invalid response

Comment: @izza What do you get if you do `console.log(now, expiry, response.data[i]['card_expiry_year'])`?

Comment: Sun Dec 30 2018 14:49:37 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time) Invalid Date

Comment: @izza and the `console.log(response.data[i]['card_expiry_year'])`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185932/discussion-between-izza-and-ross-wilson).